# How to set minLength for jQuery combobox for individual elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I set a minLength for a single element without the others been affected

**EDIT:**

Heres the plugin code

```
(function ( $ ) {
        $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
                var input,
                    self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                    wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                        .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                        .insertAfter( select );

                input = $( "<input>" )
                    .appendTo( wrapper )
                    .val( value )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 300,
                        minLength: 2,
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                            response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                                var text = $( this ).text();
                                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }) );
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                    if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if ( !valid ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                    input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

                input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };

                $( "<a>" )
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                    .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                    .appendTo( wrapper )
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                    .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                            input.autocomplete( "close" );
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $( this ).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                        input.focus();
                    });
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

I'm selecting which select tags must be made into comboboxes like this.

```
$("#tracklisting").combobox({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        var tracklisting = $("#tracklisting").val();
        var id = $("#id").val();

        $.post('writeToDB.php', {
            id: id,
            tracklisting: tracklisting
        });
    }
})
```

Where do I put `$("#tracklisting").autocomplete( "option", "minLength", 0 );` to set the length. I've tried multiple things but to no avail.

**EDIT:
Here is a jsfiddle link to the project. combox can stay on the default but combobox2 must have a minlegth of 0. http://jsfiddle.net/5cMjk/4/**

Comment: Which jquery plugin are you using for Combobox? Create a working demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @codef0rmer JqueryUI 1.8.22 ui-combobox. The simple plugin that makes an html select look and work alot better. Heres a link to the exact thing on jqueryui's site http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox. My code is basically the same in javascrpit as the demo.

Comment: I did not get your question properly, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @codef0rmer I want to change the minlength but not in the main plugin code cause that changes all of them. I only want it on the tracklisting element. Where must I put it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$("#tracklisting").autocomplete({ minLength: 2 });
```

See also: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5cMjk/1/

Comment: I have put it in every possible place that i can think of. Where exactly must i put it to make it work? `$(function() {
  $("#tracklisting").combobox();
  $("#tracklisting").autocomplete({ minLength: 0 });
  });`

Comment: check the demo above. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you can show me a demo with 2 selects and 2 different minlengths working, then i will be eternally greatful

Comment: I have updated the your demo to the combobox that I am using. If you can set a different minlegth on this then we're in business. I've tried everything you've put up to no avail. I really do appreciate all the help so far [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5cMjk/4/)

Comment: I do not know where did you get that widget codebase but I did a bit of a hack. Please note that changes are mentioned as comments in the second box. http://jsfiddle.net/5cMjk/5/

Comment: Perfect. Works like a dream. Many Many Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

The .combobox() widget from jQuery UI is a modification of .autocomplete() and doesn't seem to have as many options.

But from its code you can notice that it creates an input tag on the fly, you could try reapplying the .autocomplete() method on it again.
The input is placed in a span after the old select tag, I used .next() to select the span :

```
var myMinLength = 10;
$("#tracklisting").next().children("input").autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,

                    minLength: myMinLength ,

                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

If your combobox breaks after this, you could also try to add these lines that came after :

```
$("#tracklisting").next().children("input").addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            $("#tracklisting").next().children("input").data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };
```